# file upload error in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

php code for file uploading

```
$file_video_dir = 'uploads/apps/videos/';
            $config['upload_path'] = $file_video_dir;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|avi|mp4|3gp|mpeg|mpg|mov|mp3|flv|wmv|webm';
            $config['max_size'] = 0;
            $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
            $videoName = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_.]/', '_', preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', str_replace(' ', '_', time() . "_" . $_FILES['file_video']['name'])))); //time() . "_" .
            $config['file_name'] = $videoName;
$this->load->library('upload',$config);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('file_video')) {
                $upload_video = $final_file_video;
            } else {

                echo "<br/><br/>vieo error<br/><br/>";
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
//                $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
```

**html**

```
<input type="file" name="file_video" id="file_video" class="form-control" accept="video/*">
```

I am getting following error while fileuploading

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: Which type of file are you trying to upload?

Comment: It may happen that you are trying to upload file other than `$config['allowed_types']`.

Comment: @AjayKorat  i am trying to upload mp4 file

Comment: I think issue with ```$config['max_size'] = 0;``` you should increase this.

Comment: i have changed max size to 100 mb

Answer (score 1):

You can to go to system/libraries/upload.php file and look for

> $this->_file_mime_type($_file);

and debug it by replacing it with

> $this->_file_mime_type($_file);
>
> var_dump($this->file_type); die();

Then try uploading file and see the output in the browser and check in

> config/mimes.php

if the mime is not present there then add it there and revert the changes in the upload.php and it will be good to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am done i am not initializing the codeigniter upload library so error is occured thnx.